# Concrete example of non-nuclear operator $E \to F$ and isometry $F \hookrightarrow G$ so that the composition $E \to F \hookrightarrow G$ is nuclear

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, tensor-products

> **Question.** *Are there concrete examples of Banach spaces $E$ and $G$, a closed subspace $F \subseteq G$, and a non-nuclear operator $E \to F$ for which the composition $E \to F \hookrightarrow G$ is nuclear?*

Background: it is well-known that such operators exist, because the ideal of nuclear operators is not *injective* (see [DF93; §9.7]). The typical (non-constructive) example runs as follows:

> **Example.** (Compare [DF93; §9.8].) Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq L^2[0,1]$ be the Rademacher functions $r_n(x) = (-1)^{\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor}$, and let $R \subseteq L^2[0,1]$ be their closed linear span. Since $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal system in the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$, we may identify $R$ with $\ell^2$.
>
> It follows from the Khintchine inequality that all $L^p$ norms ($1 \leq p < \infty$) are equivalent on $R$, so in particular $R$ is a complete (and therefore closed) subspace of $L^1[0,1]$. However, by the Dunford–Pettis theorem, $L^1[0,1]$ has no reflexive, infinite-dimensional, complemented subspaces, so in particular $\ell^2 \cong R \subseteq L^1[0,1]$ is not complemented.
>
> Let $T : \ell^2 \cong R \hookrightarrow L^1[0,1]$ denote the inclusion, and consider the following commutative diagram:
>
> [image: nuclear operators diagram]
>
> (Everything is well-behaved because all spaces have the approximation property.)
> Evidently $\mathfrak{K}(\ell^2,\ell^2)$ is closed in $\mathfrak{K}(\ell^2,L^1[0,1])$, so it follows that $\mathfrak{N}(\ell^2,L^1[0,1]) \cap \mathfrak{K}(\ell^2,\ell^2)$ is closed in $\mathfrak{N}(\ell^2,L^1[0,1])$.
> We claim that this subspace is larger than the image of $\mathfrak{N}(\ell^2,\ell^2)$. To that end, note that
> \begin{align*}
> ((\ell^2)' \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} \ell^2)' &\cong \mathscr{B}\textit{i}\ell((\ell^2)' \times \ell^2) \cong \mathfrak{L}(\ell^2 , (\ell^2)'') \cong \mathfrak{L}(\ell^2 , \ell^2);\\[1ex]
> ((\ell^2)' \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} L^1[0,1])' &\cong \mathscr{B}\textit{i}\ell((\ell^2)' \times L^1[0,1]) \cong \mathfrak{L}(L^1[0,1] , (\ell^2)'') \cong \mathfrak{L}(L^1[0,1] , \ell^2).
> \end{align*}
> Under these isomorphisms, the adjoint of $\text{id} \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} T$ becomes
> $$ (\text{id} \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} T)' : \mathfrak{L}(L^1[0,1], \ell^2) \to \mathfrak{L}(\ell^2 , \ell^2), \ S \mapsto ST, $$
> which has dense range (because $\text{id} \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} T$ is injective) but is not surjective (we have $\text{id} \notin \text{ran}((\text{id} \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} T)')$ because $\ell^2$ is not complemented in $L^1[0,1]$). Hence, by duality, $\text{id} \mathbin{\tilde\otimes_\pi} T$ does not have closed range, so in particular
> $$ \mathfrak{N}(\ell^2,\ell^2) \subsetneq \mathfrak{N}(\ell^2,L^1[0,1]) \cap \mathfrak{K}(\ell^2,\ell^2). $$
> In other words, there is a non-nuclear compact operator $\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ for which $\ell^2 \to \ell^2 \hookrightarrow L^1[0,1]$ is nuclear.

This proof is non-constructive; I am asking for explicit examples.

**References.**

[DF93]: A. Defant, K. Floret, *Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals* (1993), Mathematics Studies 176,
North-Holland.

Comment: Update: [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365310/) on MathOverflow due to lack of attention. (Perhaps this is too advanced for MSE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is due to Bill Johnson on MathOverflow ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/a365325/)).

> **Proposition.** *Let $T : \ell^2 \hookrightarrow L^1[0,1]$ be as in the question. If $S : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ is absolutely $2$-summing (i.e. Hilbert–Schmidt), then $TS$ is nuclear.*
>
> *Proof.* The adjoint of a Hilbert–Schmidt operator is also Hilbert–Schmidt, and every operator $L^\infty[0,1] \to \ell^2$ is absolutely $2$-summing (cf. [DF93, §11.2]). Therefore both $S'$ and $T'$ are absolutely $2$-summing, and it follows that $S'T'$ is nuclear (cf. [DF93, §16.4]). Since $(\ell^2)'$ has the approximation property, it follows from [DF93, §5.9] that $TS$ is also nuclear. $\ \Box$

Hence a concrete example is given by any operator $S : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ which is Hilbert–Schmidt but not trace-class (for instance, a diagonal operator whose diagonal is square summable but not absolutely summable); then $S$ is not nuclear but the composition $\ell^2 \stackrel{S}{\longrightarrow} \ell^2 \hookrightarrow L^1[0,1]$ is nuclear.

**References.**

[DF93]: A. Defant, K. Floret, *Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals* (1993), Mathematics Studies 176, North-Holland.